# Print a column as row and print remaining columns under that row accordingly using shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have a raw data in this structure:

```
Date|Number|Sum

2016-05-23|128|213  
2016-05-23|121|254  
2016-05-25|143|213  
2016-05-23|111|56  
2016-05-13|121|213  
2016-05-29|111|251  
2016-05-07|111|23  
2016-05-07|143|25  
2016-05-17|111|13
```

I want header like this

```
number(2nd column)|2016-05-01|2016-05-02|....................2016-05-31
```

and print the sum (3rd column) of that particular number corresponding to that date using shell script.
I have tried using awk but not successfully.

Comment: Do you want a header-line followed by a line with sums for each number in column 2 ? Or is "number" a fixed string for the header and each row with sums should start with the number?  
And do you just want a header with all dates in a month or use the dates you find in the raw data?

Comment: Can you show your `awk` attempt and tag the question with `awk`?

Comment: I don't understand your output given your sample input. Please read [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want print all dates (first field) with the same number (second field) and then also print sum of all numbers in the third field which are corresponding to already printed dates?